# Problems after installing Alice Madness Returns game

Tags: 12.04, wine

I installed the game "Alice Madness Returns" on my Ubuntu 12.04 and everything went OK until the part where you Activate the game. I got this Error message box:

```
Program Error

The Program AliceMadnessReturns.exe has encountered a serious problem and needs to close. 
We are sorry for the inconvenience.

This can be caused by a problem in the program or a deficiency in Wine. 
You may want to check the Application Database for tips about running this application.
```

Help please. I don't know what to do. :\

Answer (score 0):

This is because the game is checking for a license.
Install PlayOnLinux and then try it out.

**Edit based on comments:** This game has been confirmed to run on Ubuntu 13.04 i386. Set Wine prefix as Windows 7 and try again.

**Try this beta script:** http://www.playonlinux.com/repository/app.php?script=863
This may or may not work on your PC.

Comment: But I already have PlayOnLinux and I run the installation with PlayOnLinux :\

Comment: Eh, I've seen this error plenty of times when I try to run software requiring a license key. Can I have your specifications, please?

Comment: Well if you mean my computer details OK then :

Comment: See my latest edit to my post.